# Android Appium - Implicit Wait on AndroidDriver Appium Doesn't Work

Tags: appium, appium-android

I've some problem with AndroidDriver in Appium, 
Currently I am using this code to wait several time to give my App Log in / Registration process.

BasePage Class :

```
protected AndroidDriver driver;
public BasePage(AndroidDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
public void waitFor(int second)  {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(second, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

and implement on this class :

```
public class RegistrationPage extends base.BasePage {
    public RegistrationPage(AndroidDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}

public RegistrationPage alreadyExistRegistration()  {
    waitForVisibilityOf(button_login);
    swipeAndroid(1000, 1000, 100, 1000);
    waitFor(1);
    swipeAndroid(1000, 1000, 100, 1000);
    waitFor(1);
    swipeAndroid(1000, 1000, 100, 1000);
    waitFor(1);
    driver.findElement(button_register).click();
    driver.findElement(input_dob).click();
    driver.findElement(ok).click();
    driver.findElement(phone_no).sendKeys("888888888");
    driver.findElement(setup_pin).sendKeys("1111");
    driver.findElement(confirm_pin).sendKeys("1111");
    tapAndroid(840,1832);
    driver.findElement(check_term).click();
    driver.findElement(btn_next).click();
    waitFor(10);
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(message).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Your Number is Already Registered"));
```

I have edited the parameter up to 50 second but there is no wait in Junit test. Before using AndroidDriver I am using WebDriver and it works well, but I need Android Driver to do TouchAction. 
So my test case always fail because when the assert run it will find element immediately while it is not available yet.

Comment: i am having the same issue. Currently i am using **ExplicitWait** and **Thread.sleep()** method.

Comment: yeah, for now i am using Thread.sleep() from java it self. will try ExplicitWait, i hope this also works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the concept of implicit waits wrong. We don't need to set it every time. We need to set it once while driver initialization with maximum time out like 60 secs and it will wait for element when finding it.

Along with it, you can use explicit wait with a time out value greater than 1 minute like,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 120);
```

And use it's method,

```
wait.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated (By.id ("your ID")));
```

Once this is done, you don't need to call `waitFor` methods everywhere in your code.

This is working fine for me and I never use `Thread.sleep()` .

Comment: actually i have create this function : 
    `protected void waitForVisibilityOf(By locator) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
    }`

and called on the implementation like this :
    `waitForVisibilityOf(button_login);`
but this doesn't work. i think because i am using Android Driver previously using Web Driver and it works.